# Oracle Bitmap Join Index

Tags: oracle, oracle19c

I am trying to create Bitmap Join Index in Oracle Database 19c but encounter the error below:

```
Error starting at line : 7 in command -
CREATE BITMAP INDEX cust_sales_bji ON sales(c.cust_city) 
  FROM sales s, customers c 
  WHERE c.cust_id = s.cust_id LOCAL
Error report -
ORA-25954: missing primary key or unique constraint on dimension
25954. 00000 -  "missing primary key or unique constraint on dimension\n"
*Cause:    An attempt to create a join index was made, which failed
           because one or more dimensions did not have an appropriate
           constraint matching the join conditions.
*Action:   Ensure that the where clause is correct (contains all of the
           constraint columns) and that an enforced constraint is on
           each dimension table.
```

The dimension table customer does have Primary Key constraint. You can check the DDL for both tables customer and sales below:

[DDL for Sales table](https://drive.google.com/file/d/14EZ0jSDMpNW4kCIYTLPimX4cvJeSkljC/view?usp=sharing)

[DDL for customers table](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CU3fwQDCoc74lae91SZzpQv-Ul9hUeCE/view?usp=sharing)

**1st Edit Based on Wernfried Domscheit's Comment:**

As Wernfried Domscheit's suggestion, the Sales table must have Primary Key as well. So I created another `SALES_BITMAP` table as below:

```
  CREATE TABLE "SH"."SALES_BITMAP" 
   (    "SALES_ID" NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE  NOKEEP  NOSCALE , 
    "PROD_ID" NUMBER, 
    "CUST_ID" NUMBER, 
    "TIME_ID" DATE, 
    "CHANNEL_ID" NUMBER, 
    "PROMO_ID" NUMBER, 
    "QUANTITY_SOLD" NUMBER(10,2), 
    "AMOUNT_SOLD" NUMBER(10,2)
   )

  ALTER TABLE "SH"."SALES_BITMAP" ADD CONSTRAINT "SALES_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("SALES_ID")
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS"  ENABLE;
```

I populated the data in `SALES_BITMAP` table from the `SALES` table then running the statement to create the bitmap join index but still get the same error:

```
Error starting at line : 12 in command -
CREATE BITMAP INDEX cust_sales_bji ON SALES_BITMAP(c.cust_city) 
  FROM SALES_BITMAP s, customers c 
  WHERE c.cust_id = s.cust_id LOCAL
Error report -
ORA-25954: missing primary key or unique constraint on dimension
25954. 00000 -  "missing primary key or unique constraint on dimension\n"
*Cause:    An attempt to create a join index was made, which failed
           because one or more dimensions did not have an appropriate
           constraint matching the join conditions.
*Action:   Ensure that the where clause is correct (contains all of the
           constraint columns) and that an enforced constraint is on
           each dimension table.
```

How can I create the bitmap join index in this case ?

Kind regards,

Ken Masters

Comment: Can you please reduce the DDL to relevant information. Nobody cares about column comments or your storage clauses.

Comment: The error message is quite clear, there is no primary key. You have only a UNIQUE INDEX which is not a primary key.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit, I tried to provide all relevant information from the DDL as there might be some behavior that I am not aware of in the DDL itself. Again, The customers table does have the Primary Key `ALTER TABLE "SH"."CUSTOMERS" ADD CONSTRAINT "CUSTOMERS_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("CUST_ID")
  USING INDEX "SH"."CUSTOMERS_PK"  ENABLE NOVALIDATE;`

Comment: You provided way too much, nobody is going to read it. You should provide the code as text in the question, external drives might be blocked by corporate security. Anyway, the `SALES` table does not have a primary key.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit , I have edited my question regarding the primary key column in `SALES` table but still get the same error

Comment: Looks like the primary key must be on `cust_id`, not `SALES_ID`

Comment: If that is the case, then the bitmap join index is meaningless as it joins 2 Primary Keys from 2 tables. The purpose is to derived the dimensional data from the `customers` table, therefore `cust_id` in the `sales` table must be a foreign key column. Furthermore, the error states that Primary Key or Unique constraint on the dimension table (which is `customers`), So fact table (which is `SALES`) should not be required to have Primary Key.